# How to show 404 page for uppercase URLs in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Generally, WordPress redirects the Uppercase URLs to Lowercase by default. But for some cases, you need only lowercase URLs and a 404 page for uppercase URLs. You can do that in various ways and I tried this one in my scenario.

```
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);
if(preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $uri_segments[2])){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: ".home_url('/404page/'));
    exit();
}
```

Take the segments from URI and check or compare each string in URI. I hope this will help.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply host your WordPress application on a server environment that uses an Apache web server. Apache is case-sensitive by default, and there will be no need to implement any custom PHP code in your WordPress for that. Your web server will do all the work for you.